# Having a single handler for an endpoint would be against REST principles?

Tags: python, rest, web-services, flask, crud

Regarding  [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) tutorial (**Miguel Grinberg: RESTful apps with Flask**), I've come across some doubts.

The tutorial shows the creation of a resource with multiple routes and each one of them, has a different behaviour.

[image]

My question is regarding REST architecture:

- Would it be against the REST principles, to have a more compact construction for a resource, instead of having multiple routes for each HTTP verb?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                      
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def tasks(task_id=None):                                                    
    if task_id is None:                                                         
        if request.method == "GET":                                             
            pass                                                                
        elif request.method == "POST":                                          
            pass                                                                
    else:                                                                       
        if request.method == "GET":                                             
            pass                                                                
        elif request.method == "PUT":                                           
            pass                                                                
        elif request.method == "DELETE":                                        
            pass
```

Comment: Your code will never ever be against the REST principles, it is just related to method, url and action on resource. But never to how you implement it.

Comment: But putting the handling of all requests in a single function will make it more difficult to maintain your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be against the REST principles, to have a more compact construction for a resource, instead of having multiple routes for each HTTP verb?

No.

Neither REST nor HTTP care how you implement your message handlers.  They only care about the semantics of the messages.  As long as your implementation's responses are indistinguishable from those of a boring hypermedia document store, you are good.